# Server Connection Error in Jupyter Notebook - keeps on popping up

Tags: server, jupyter-notebook

While using the jupyter notebook, a pop up with the error warning "A connection to the Jupyter server could not be established. JupyterLab will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or Jupyter server configuration." keeps on popping up. I'm sure that this has nothing to do with my WiFi connection as it is running perfectly.

**My System Specification**
OS: Windows 11 Home (22H2)
RAM: 8 GB
GPU: Nvidia GTX 1080
Browser: Google Chrome (Version 114.0.5735.110)

**Jupyter Version**
IPython          : 8.13.2
ipykernel        : 6.23.1
ipywidgets       : 8.0.6
jupyter_client   : 8.2.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.0
jupyter_server   : 2.6.0
jupyterlab       : 4.0.1
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.4.0
nbformat         : 5.9.0
notebook         : 6.5.4
qtconsole        : 5.4.3
traitlets        : 5.9.0

As the pop-up mentioned that error is based on either network connection or Jupyter server configuration, I did all I can by fixing my network issues. All other internet application runs fine. Even though this pop-up keeps on popping up, it doesn't affect any of the program so far. However it irritates and would be better if the error is solved completely.